# running c++ program which contains posix api in fedora

Tags: c++, unix, posix, fedora

I have installed `fedora` and want to execute a cpp program in it. This program contains `POSIX` related concepts like using `_SC_CLK_TCK` or `_SC_CHILD_MAX` etc.

Please tell me the steps to run this or any steps or installations in fedora required.

Answer (score 2):

Those variables aren't in defined Fedora. You need to modify the source code of your program to use `CLK_TCK` and `CHILD_MAX` instead.

If you run `getconf -a` you can see all of the `sysconf` variables that are defined for your system. In general, you want the one with the most similar name to the missing one.